# International transfer in euro. Used swift code for wrong branch. What should I do?

Tags: money-transfer, swift

Two days ago I transferred money from my Israeli account to my German account, but used GENODED1SPE instead of GENODED1SPW for the swift code. This code does exist, but belongs to a different branch of the same bank. I did use the correct IBAN and recipient name.
What should I do? Contacting the Israeli bank is generally a huge PITA for me since I don't really speak Hebrew and it's difficult to get someone in the phone to speaks good English in my experience
Should I just wait and hope that the money is either transferred or returned? What are the chances of neither of these things happening? Is there any benefit of acting right now and not waiting?

EDIT: Money did arrive today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the IBAN is correct it should work out. It stand for international bank account number and hence should be unique. So there is no other account with the same IBAN but a different Swift code.

I would wait say twice as long as a transfer from Israel to Germany usually takes (should be a couple of days) and expect that the money goes through without problems. If after that much time the money has not arrived and has not been refunded to your original account, you need to contact the bank and figure out what happened.